# how to avoid nested document's property assignment that results in undefined

Tags: reactjs

This is how my incoming object from server looks like:

```
{
   "name":"product1",
    "categories": {
        "cat1": {
            "supported": false
        },
        "cat2": {
            "supported": true
        }
}
```

When the page loads, I will have 100s of categories and I populate categories object based on which category user selects. Those categories that were not selected by the user, don't exist in the product object.

When user is trying to edit the product, I have to show all the 100 categories in the checkboxes and show those categories checked which as `supported` set to true.

This is how my checkbox looks like:

```
data.props.categories.map((category, index) =>
    <Form.Checkbox defaultChecked={productData.categories[category._id].supported} label={category.displayname}></Form.Checkbox>
);
```

This throws me an error saying when a category does not exist in product object because I am trying to access `supported` property of an undefined object. I am able to achieve what I need by writing a function that checks if a particular category exists in the incoming products object or not.

```
const isCategorySupported = (category_id) => {
    debugger
    if (productData.categories.hasOwnProperty(category_id)) {
        return productData.categories[category_id].supported
    }
    return false

};

<Form.Checkbox defaultChecked={isCategorySupported(category._id)} label={category.displayname}></Form.Checkbox>
```

I was wondering if there is a better way or `react` way of doing this without writing a function?

Comment: This looks ok, you may also use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: @Trisma: that does what I was trying to do in the function. Is there some sort of browser compatibility I need to worry about? If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Well optional chaining is not a fully supported feature in browsers, so. a babel conversion will be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine. You may use optional chaining for this if you want a more elegant way:

```
<Form.Checkbox 
  defaultChecked={productData?.categories?.[category_id]?.supported}
  label={category.displayname}>
</Form.Checkbox>
```

You have to keep in mind that this is not natively supported in the browsers just yet so a babel setup will be needed for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to map through `categories` object. So, you should be able to do like:

```
Object.keys(data.props.categories).map((category, index) =>
    <Form.Checkbox defaultChecked={data.props.categories[category].supported} label={data.props.categories[category].displayname}></Form.Checkbox>
);
```